# Unity3d iphone game development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unity-game-engine

i want to know is there any getting started tutorials with unity3d iphone development. i also have not seen any tutorial which has used objective C language for developing in unity. so kindly tell me if there is any with objective C.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know for a fact that Objective-C is supported by Unity 3D for iPhone; my company has made a game with it. In the end, however, we found it to be quite sluggish. We only had 6 super simple models on the screen and the engine had difficulty rendering them (they weren't fast, and the physics were extremely simple) even on the iPhone 4. Ultimately, we were not impressed with the engine and wish we would have used OpenGL ES for that project.

Comment: but AFAIK unity3D also supports OpenGL ES. and can you please give me some link which has some samples to get started with unity3D in objective C?

Comment: [Here](http://www.bleepng.com/blog/2009/05/unity-iphone-touch-animation-tutorial/) [are](http://learnunity3d.com/category/tutorials/) [some](http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/).