# Can Objective C be used as a programming language for developing games in Unity3d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unity-game-engine

Apart from C#, JavaScript and Boo, can one use Objective C as a programming language for developing 3d games for iPhone/iPad in Unity3D?

Comment: this may be a [duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677619/unity3d-iphone-game-development)

Comment: That means use of Objective C is not recommended. Thanks.

Comment: @Arshad the linked question does not tell anything about recommendation of objectiveC but generally says that unity was slow (which is not true).

Comment: @Till- I've probably found something inside stackoverflow. It tells about the three supported [languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725877/some-ideas-about-game-programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Objective-C as a programming language for developing games in Unity3d.
[Unity iPhone Examples](http://unity3d.com/support/resources/example-projects/iphone-examples)

Comment: I know that you can call objective-C code from Unity script. but can you actually use Objective-C only to define the whole behavior?!

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few 3D games (and some top ones at that) run on the Unity3 engine, it is no longer slow or sluggish and can save you a LOT of development time.

Check out the [Unity3 iOS page.](http://unity3d.com/unity/publishing/ios)

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You cannot use Objective C to completely write your game code. Supported languages are C#, Javascript and Boo. (Though Unity is no more providing Boo's scripting reference)

Below is the reference of unity scripting documents which contains details of API usage in C# and Javascript.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/